# Will Spark pick up new files from a directory once processing has started?

Tags: apache-spark

If I use

```
sc.textFile("/my/dir1")
```

to make RDDs for all files in a directory, and there is another application already writing in there (so, if the processing is long, new files will be added), will spark also get the new ones, or just those found at startup? (I'd really need the latter...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is NO. The reason is RDD or Dataframe is an immutable data-structure. Once you created an RDD/Dataframe there is no way to append to that data structure.

When you read the data in a directory, spark will create in RDD which keeps track of the partitions in the read data. This RDD then is not mutable. So spark will continue with the execution with the partitions that found at startup

Alternative to this is to use the spark streaming where the new data are discovered when they are added to the directory.

Comment: Well maybe you should look at streaming option

Comment: I don't need the streaming option because I don't want it to pick up the new files. Thanks